# If I use defaultChecked, sorting table columns does not change the position of the checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I use "defaultChecked", sorting table columns does not change the position of the checkbox.
If use "checked", I can change position but checkbox doesn't work correctly.
How can I fix it? 
Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/sakanyan/e2a56mbk/29/

```
enter code here
<input  type="checkbox" checked={item.hasItem} /*OR 
defaultChecked={item.hasItem} */ />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    //....
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
}

//...

onCheck(event) {
   let s = Object.assign({}, this.state);
   let d = s.data.find( s => s.id == e.target.name );
   if( !d ) return;
   d.hasItem = !d.hasItem;
   this.setState(s);
}

render() {
    //...
   <input name = {item.id} type='checkbox' checked={item.hasItems} onChange={this.onCheck} />
    //...
}
```

Previously, you're checkbox were never updated (in state) so the sort appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    state = {
       hasItems = false;
    }
}

handleCheck = event => {
   this.setState({hasItems : !this.state.hasItems })
}

render(){
   return(
   //....
   <input  
      type="checkbox" 
      checked={this.state.hasItem}
      onChange={this.handleCheck}
   >
   //....
   )
}
```